# Storing an array of 2d arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, malloc

I'm trying to store a series of matrices in a contiguous block of memory, and then retrieve them. Each array will be the same size (n x n).

As far as I understand, what I need to do is:

1. Allocate and initialize each array that I need to store/retrieve.
2. Allocate a contiguous block of memory of size `(# arrays) * sizeof (1 array)` and assign a pointer, `***matrices`, to the beginning of the block
3. Copy each array into the block at `matrices[0]`, `matrices[1]`, ...
4. Print them by sending `matrices[0]`, `matrices[1]`, ... to a `matrix_print` function

Now, obviously I am misunderstanding something, because it isn't working. This is the output I get right before it crashes:

```
Matrix A is 16 bytes.
Matrix B is 16 bytes.
So, we will allocate 32 bytes in row_blocks.
Matrix A:
| 1  1 |
| 2  2 |
Matrix B:
| 2  2 |
|
```

Here is the code for my test case that I'm trying to get working:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void matrix_print(int dim, int ***matrix);
void matrix_init(int dim, int matrix[dim][dim], int val);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int dim = 2;

    int A[dim][dim], B[dim][dim];

    matrix_init(dim, A, 1);
    matrix_init(dim, B, 2);

    printf("Matrix A is %d bytes.\n", sizeof A);
    printf("Matrix B is %d bytes.\n", sizeof B);

    int ***matrices = malloc(sizeof A + sizeof B);

    printf("So, we will allocate %d bytes in matrices.\n\n",
            sizeof A + sizeof B);

    memcpy(matrices[0], A, sizeof (A));
    memcpy(matrices[1], B, sizeof (B));

    printf("Matrix A:\n");
    matrix_print(dim, &matrices[0]);
    printf("Matrix B:\n");
    matrix_print(dim, &matrices[1]);

    return 0;
}

void matrix_print(int dim, int ***matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        printf("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
     }
}

void matrix_init(int dim, int matrix[dim][dim], int val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = val;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joy of two-dimensional matrices in C!

When you pass a one-dimensional array `int[dim]` to a function, it decays into a pointer to its first element, `int *` or `int[]`, losing the information on its size in the process.

A two-dimensional array `int[dim][dim]` does not decay into a double pointer, `int **`, but into a pointer to the first element of a row of size `dim` of ints, `int (*)[dim]` or `int[][dim]`. That is, because multi-dimensional arrays of constant row-size are treated specially; they are implemented as contiguous data blocks where the constant size is used to calculate the indices. (Constant here means constant for all rows and throughout all matrix operations; as in your case this value can be a variable in C99.)

Your matrices of type `int[dim][dim]` can't be represented as `int **`, so you should adjust the type of your matrix array:

```
int (*matrices)[dim][dim];

matrices = malloc(sizeof A + sizeof B);
```

The signature of your printing function also changes:

```
void matrix_print(int dim, int matrix[dim][dim])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        printf("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
     }
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
matrix_print(dim, matrices[0]);
```

without the address-of operator `&`.

Footnotes:

- `int (*x)[dim]` is a pointer to an array of integer of length `dim`. `int *x[dim]` is an array of length `dim` of pointers to `int`.
- The special treatment is owed to how Fortran stores multi-dimensional arrays, I think. If, on the other hand, you have allocated an array of pointers, they are `int **`. Such data structures can hold ragged matrices.
- The matrices are C99-style arrays with variable lengths (VLA), which cannot be initialised, so the `malloc` has to be a separate declaration and assignment.

Comment: Got it working, thank you so much. I had actually tried int `*matrices[dim][dim]` earlier and gotten confused because it wouldn't allow VLAs. It works with the parentheses though `int *(matrices)[dim][dim]`!